# Confusion regarding Ward identities in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, ward-identity

Let $\cal S$ be an action for a QFT for the field $\phi$. Suppose $\phi(x) \to \phi(x) +\epsilon \delta \phi$ be an infinitesimal global symmetry of the action. I am trying to understand the associated Ward identity for the symmetry. We proceed as usual. We Consider a local operator $\cal O(x_1)$. Then
\begin{equation}
\langle \cal O(x_1)\rangle=\int \cal{D} \phi e^{-S[\phi]} O(x_1).
\end{equation}
Now we make a change of variables $\phi \to \phi'(\phi)$, so that
\begin{equation}
\langle \cal O(x_1)\rangle=\int\cal D \phi'^{-S[\phi']}O'(x_1).
\end{equation}
Now if $\phi \to \phi'(\phi)=\phi+\epsilon \delta \phi$ is a global symmetry transformation then we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \cal O(x_1)\rangle &&=\int\cal D \phi^{-S[\phi]}\left(O(x_1)+\epsilon \delta O(x_1)\right)\\
\implies \langle \delta \cal {O(x_1)}\rangle&&=0.
\end{eqnarray}
Instead of a global transformation, if we make a local transformation $\phi(x)\to \phi(x)+\epsilon(x)\delta\phi(x)$, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \cal O(x_1)\rangle &&=\int\cal D \phi^{-S[\phi]-\int d^4x~J^\mu\partial_\mu \epsilon }\left(O(x_1)+\epsilon(x_1) \delta O(x_1)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\cal J^\mu$ is the (classically) conserved current. To first order in $\epsilon$, this gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\epsilon(x_1)\langle \delta\cal O (x_1) \rangle=\int d^4 x~\partial_\mu \epsilon \langle J^\mu O(x_1)\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}
Assuming that the current $\cal J^\mu$ vanishes at infinity, this can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\epsilon(x_1)\langle \delta\cal O (x_1) \rangle=-\int d^4 x~ \epsilon(x)\partial_\mu \langle J^\mu O(x_1)\rangle\\
&&\implies \partial_\mu \langle \cal J^\mu O(x_1)\rangle=-\langle \delta O(x_1)\rangle \delta (x-x_1).
\end{eqnarray}
This is what many textbooks such as "Conformal Field Theory by David Sénéchal, Philippe Francesco, and Pierre Mathieu" write. But from the global symmetry of the action, we have already established that $\langle \delta O(x_1)\rangle=0$. This would imply that $\partial_\mu \langle \mathcal{J
}^\mu O(x_1)\rangle= 0$, *identically*. It will be helpful if someone points out what am I missing here.

Comment: Why do you think that the final identity is false?

Comment: @NiharKarve Because in the book "Conformal Field Theory by David Sénéchal, Philippe Francesco, and Pierre Mathieu", they did not set it to zero (see for example Eq. 2.157).

Comment: Note the final answer does not depend upon $\epsilon$ and constant $\epsilon$ is a special case of non-constant $\epsilon$. Necessarily both derivations should result in the same answer, so you know something has gone wrong. The answer will be that the above derivations have been a little too caviler about discarding total derivatives.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. What is your concern?

Comment: @PraharMitra Actually I was trying to read the paper "Infinite conformal symmetry in two-dimensional quantum field theory" by Belavin, Polyakov, and Zamolodchikov. In this paper, they write in Eq. 2.4 that "$\partial_a\langle T^{ab}\chi \rangle=0$ except at the points $\xi_1, \xi_2,.....,\xi_n$". Why it is not true identically?

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee the correlator you are considering has just one operator. The one considered by BPZ has many operators.

Comment: @PraharMitra I see. I thought BPZ statement is a general statement.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee I don’t understand how you teach that conclusion. BPZs result is completely general. It holds when there are n operators in the correlator for any non negative integer n. In the special case of $n=1$ it reduces to your result.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee I mean *reach, not teach, sorry.

Comment: @PraharMitra I meant for the special case that I have considered (just one operator) BPZ statement would read "$\partial_a\langle T^{ab} O(x_1)\rangle=0 $ except at the point $x=x_1$" while I am getting it is equal to zero everywhere.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee - The full correct statement by BPZ is "$\partial_a \langle T^{ab} O(x_1) \rangle = 0$ except at the point $x=x_1$ where it is equal to $\langle \delta O(x_1) \rangle \delta^{(d)}(x-x_1)$". However, due to a separate property, it just so happens that $\langle \delta O(x_1) \rangle = 0$ so in this special case, the result by BPZ would simplify to "$\partial_a \langle T^{ab} O(x_1) \rangle = 0$ everywhere." The original BPZ statement is more general and correct. You need to use a separate property to prove the last statement.

Comment: @PraharMitra I get it now. Thanks.